# access oracle DB on remote linux server using php

Tags: php, linux, oracle

I want to access an Oracle database that is on a remote Linux server with my company's intranet.

Currently I can access it through Excel and a System DSN on my Windows 7 machine.  But I am running into difficulties with multiple queries in my excel spreadsheet, so I want to create a web page that does the same thing using PHP.

I have the name of the server that the DB is on, but I cannot get any response, either good or bad from my queries.  I have read about web

Here is an example of the connection script:

```
//Data Source=username/password@//myserver:1521/my.service.com;
echo "set up db connection.<Br>";
$db = oci_connect('userid', 'password', 'server/db');


 if (!$db) {
    echo "no db. <br>";
$e = oci_error();
if (!$e) { 
    echo "no oci errors. <br>";
        }
else {
       trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message'], ENT_QUOTES), E_USER_ERROR);
       }
}
else {
echo "DB, yes <br>";
}

if ($db->connect_error) {
echo "Connection errors. <br>";
die('Connect Error ('. $db->connect_errno .') '. $db->connect_error);
}
else {
echo "no connection errors.<br>";
}

echo 'Success, db info:   '. $db->host_info .'.<br>';
```

Comment: Please show your EXACT oci_connect value for the 3rd parameter.  It either needs to be a TNS entry or a fully qualified connection string as detailed here - http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e10836/naming.htm

Comment: The third parameter is the IP and db_name as zoracle2/sst_prod_db

Comment: I also tried using this format:     $MYDB =
     "(DESCRIPTION =
       (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = zoracle2)(PORT = 1521))
       (CONNECT_DATA =
         (SERVER = DEDICATED)
         (SERVICE_NAME = sst_prod_db)
       )
     )
";

Comment: So what error do you get after calling oci_connect?  Nothing?

Comment: HTTP 500 error (Internal Server error).